# Batch script: Problems with SET in an IF

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, set

The problem is that my `set tap=c:\ca\sf\1st 2nd...` etc. isn't working at all.
The `echo` shows nothing, the `set` isn't putting the path in the variable for some reason.
I got all `if`s right, is there another problem?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

    if NEWYORK == %region% (  
        set tap=C:\ny  
        CALL :process %1 %2 %tap% %cl%  
        GOTO :EOF  
    )  
    if California == %region% (  
        if '%3'=='sanfrancisco' (  
            set cl=c:\ca\sf\cl  
            if '%2'=='1st' set tap=c:\ca\sf\1st  
            if '%2'=='2nd' set tap=c:\ca\sf\2nd  
            if '%2'=='3rd' set tap=c:\ca\sf\3rd  
            if '%2'=='4th' set tap=c:\ca\sf\4th  
            if '%2'=='5th' set tap=c:\ca\sf\5th  
            echo %tap%, echo %cl%,  
            pause  
            CALL :process %1 %2 %tap% %cl%  
            GOTO :EOF  
        )  
        if '%3' == 'LosAngeles' (  
            set tap=c:\ca\la  
            set cl=c:\ca\la\cl  
            echo %tap%, %cl%  
            pause  
            CALL :process %1 %2 %tap% %cl%  
            GOTO :EOF  
        )  
        set tap=c:\USA  
        set cl=c:\usa\cl  
        echo %tap%, %cl%  
        pause  
        CALL :process %1 %2 %tap% %cl%  
        GOTO :EOF ) else (  
        echo faiiiiiiiiiillllllllll  
        pause  
        GOTO :END)  
    endlocal  
    GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: what happens if you run the script without enabledelayedexpansion? and whats your ":process"?

Comment: If the set *and* the echo don't work, most likely that whole branch isn't executed.

Comment: everything else is working but the "set = tap=c:\ca\sf\1st 2nd 3rd etc...
without the enabledelayed its not working at all, my :process is another code else where, its working well if i dont put this part of the code..

Comment: As Aacini wrote you need to use the delayed expansion, instead of `CALL :process %1 %2 %tap% %cl%` you need `CALL :process %1 %2 !tap! %cl%`

Answer (score 2):

You missed the first SET command. The line

```
tap=C:\ny
```

must be

```
set tap=C:\ny
```

When you use a variable that is modified inside an IF or FOR its value must be expanded with !var! and not with %var%; otherwise the expanded value is the value the variable had BEFORE enter the IF or FOR (this is the objective of EnableDelayedExpansion). For example:

```
set var=Old value
if 1 == 1 (
    set var=New value
    echo With percent: %var%. With exclamation: !var!
)
```

Previous segment show: `With percent: Old value. With exclamation: New value`

An additional comment:

Although `if NEWYORK == %region%` is the same as `if %region% == NEWYORK` when it is executed, the second one is customary and clearer from programmers point of view.

**EDIT**

I slightly modified your code. Take a look at it:

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

    if /I %region% == NEWYORK (  
        set tap=C:\ny  
        REM cl IS NOT DEFINED HERE, BUT USED IN NEXT LINE
        CALL :process %1 %2 !tap! !cl!
        GOTO :EOF  
    )  

    if /I %region% == California (  
        if /I '%3' == 'sanfrancisco' (  
            set cl=c:\ca\sf\cl  
            set tap=c:\ca\sf\%2
            echo !tap!, !cl!
            pause  
            CALL :process %1 %2 !tap! !cl!
            GOTO :EOF  
        )  
        if /I '%3' == 'LosAngeles' (  
            set tap=c:\ca\la  
            set cl=c:\ca\la\cl  
            echo !tap!, !cl!  
            pause  
            CALL :process %1 %2 !tap! !cl!
            GOTO :EOF  
        )  
        set tap=c:\USA  
        set cl=c:\usa\cl  
        echo !tap!, !cl!
        pause  
        CALL :process %1 %2 !tap! !cl!
        GOTO :EOF
    ) else (  
        echo faiiiiiiiiiillllllllll  
        pause  
        GOTO :END
    )  
    endlocal  
    GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: ya tried it already, problem isnt with the ! or % its with the "set" in the "if"